# Greek letter in ggtitle will not become italic bold in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, fonts, ggtitle

[image: the tau symbol is not bold italic like the rest of the title]

```
plot19 <- ggplot(FoBlandAlt.apex, aes(x = avg, y = perc)) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = percent_mean_diff) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = lower.perc, color = "black", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = upper.perc, color = "black", linetype="dashed") +
  ggtitle(expression(bolditalic(tau~(s) ~~STATSports))) +
  ylab("Difference from Criterion") +
  xlab("Mean")+theme_light()+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size=10),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size=10),
    title = element_text(color= "black", size = 6, face = "bold.italic")
  )
```

I have the title set up the way I want, but for some reason the tau symbol (τ) wont turn bolditalic like the rest of the text

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  labs(title = "τ(s) STATSports") +
  theme(title = element_text(face = "bold.italic"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "plain"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but I need to mathematical small letter tau. Its has the unicode character U+1D70F, but this is not working on my end

Comment: it should be the mathematical character

Comment: Ive added more of the code I used